# How-to integrate Paypal with WinForm Desktop Application

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, winforms, paypal

I would like to enable my Windows Forms Desktop Application to integrate with PayPal so I can charge my users through the WinForms app. Are there any resources regarding this, or can it be done?

Answer (score 4):

I may have just found a solution.

Visit this web page, over at PayPal:
https://www.x.com/community/ppx/apps101

Quote:

> Adaptive APIs let you to do more than
>   just accept payments on your website.
>   You can also:
>
> Integrate payments into your
>   application

So, they've just said that you can interact with their API from within an application, not just on websites.

Also, there is this link:
https://www.x.com/community/ppx/code_samples     which includes lots of source code samples of C++ and VB.NET and C# (Windows Forms).

The information on those pages, along with the other resources listed there should be enough to get you started.

Hope this helps.

Edit: probably this is the intended URL:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/adaptive-payments/