# Accept Payments from PayPal via Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, paypal, payment

I am trying to find out if it's possible to Accept Payments from PayPal via Windows Forms Application - but haven't found much info yet. Is it possible to do this?

I don't want any redirection/browser controls/etc in my app. I just want to use some kinda API or something from PayPal. But i've been going around in circles on their x.com, still can't find anything about it.

Comment: Good luck with that - anyone that enters their credit card details into any-old-app is asking for trouble - you're best leaving it to the professionals.

Comment: Sure it's possible. They don't seem to have a WinForms SDK but they have SOAP and NVP API's which you can code against directly. It's all thoroughly documented here: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/home

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1812944/726631

Comment: @LightWing - Lol, thanks for that link. I was actually the person who posted the answer on that question on my old account. But I just couldn't find it when searching SO

Comment: wow, so my comment was great,hehe.

Comment: @LightWing - Indeed it was lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now in 2023 one must use Paypal restful API or other solutions.

https://developer.paypal.com/home

Comment: Um, this isn't for ASP.NET though

Comment: No different , Web services work with Winforms Application as well as asp.net

Comment: If u don't know about web services, it is another problem.

Comment: Web services can use with mobile application,web application(PHP,ASP.NET,etc) and ...

Comment: Readers beware, the solutions in this answer are critically outdated.