# Integration of Paypal API with .Net Windows Forms Application and WPF Application

Tags: wpf, winforms, desktop-application, paypal, windowsformsintegration

I have to integrate Paypal API with .Net Windows Form (Desktop) application, so that i can get all the transaction details, payments details and all other information, at my windows forms application. How can i integrate PaypalAPI with Windows Forms and WPF based application, is there any link or resources? Thanks

Comment: duplicate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812944/how-to-integrate-paypal-with-winform-desktop-application)

Comment: do you have nay any answer for the given question?

Comment: what you have tried so fa, update your question